# optical scattering cross section and polarization tensor

Tags: optics, non-linear-optics, optical-materials

The optical scattering and absorption cross sections are well known to be

$$
 C_{sca} = \frac{k^4}{6\pi}|\alpha|^2 \qquad C_{abs} = k\Im (\alpha)
$$

where $k$ is the wavevector and $\alpha$ is the polarizability. In the case the polarizability is no longer just a number but a tensor than, in a cartesian coordinate system, I would write

$$\hat{\alpha} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    \alpha_{xx}  &  \alpha_{xy} &  \alpha_{xz}\\
    \alpha_{yx}  &  \alpha_{yy} &  \alpha_{yz}\\
    \alpha_{zx} &  \alpha_{zy}  &  \alpha_{zz}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I know for sure that the polarizability in the absorption cross section is replaced with its trace

$$
 C_{abs} = k \mathrm{Tr} \Im( \hat{\alpha} )
$$

Could you confirm or neglect that, in the some way, the scattering cross section is

$$
 C_{sca} = \frac{k^4}{6\pi}\mathrm{Tr}|\hat{\alpha}|^2
$$

and, in any cases, could you provide mea reference about it? 
Thank you